# Bulk Edit Formulas using Rgex

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a set of formulas in many cells, and I want to bulk-edit them by a dollar sign to self-reference them.

Here's an example of the formulas:

`=if(Attendance!$AG$722<>"", IF(COUNTIF(Attendance!$AL$1031:$AL$1038, Attendance!F750), INDEX(Attendance!$AM$1031:$AM$1038, MATCH(Attendance!F750, Attendance!$AL$1031:$AL$1038, 0)), 0), IF(COUNTIF(Attendance!$AL$1031:$AL$1038, Attendance!G750), INDEX(Attendance!$AM$1031:$AM$1038, MATCH(Attendance!G750, Attendance!$AL$1031:$AL$1038, 0)), 0))`

I want to add a dollar sign next to the following:

- `Attendance!F750` to become `Attendance!$F$750`
- `Attendance!G750` to become `Attendance!$G$750`

To keep in mind:

- There are other cells like that contain 2 letters like (AC, AB, etc...). You can check the [Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rZgPG_uTCuPm5XSi423v0xUbPKyGQsvfP3QbLDfZBas/edit?usp=sharing) sheet that contains all the formulas I want to edit.
- The edit should only look for cells that don't have a dollar sign, not the ranges that already have them like: `Attendance!$AL$1031`

I tried editing this using Regex with the help of ChatGPT 4 and Google Bard. They both failed because the expressions just messed up my formulas.

Here are all the expressions they suggested which didn't work:

ChatGPT 4:

In the "Find" field, input `(Attendance!)([A-Z])(\d+)`

In the "Replace with" field, input `$1$$2$$3`

==============

Find: `(Attendance!)([^$A-Z]*[A-Z][^$A-Z]*)(\d+)`

Replace with: `$1$$2$$3`

Google Bard:

In the Find field, type the following regular expression: `(?<!\$)([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)`.

In the Replace with field, type the following: `$1$2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your provided -in your Demo sheet - formula you can use the following regex

Try the `Edit`-->`Find and replace`
No need to use a formula

[image]

---

**What the regex does**:

- It searches for the pattern `(dance!)(\D+)(\d+)(,|\))`. That is any single cell reference that consists of 4 groups. It ends in `dance!`, followed by `1 or more letters`, `1 or more numbers` and  `,` or `)` like `Attendance!AI715)` or maybe `Attendance!I743,`
- Replaces every single instance with `$1$$$2$$$3$4`
- It is applied to  to **all formulae** within the specified range (`Sheet1!F5:NG5`)

Comment: Thanks, bro! It worked well. I still don't understand why GPT and Bard failed to provide this answer, even though it's not complicated.

I was wondering why you added groups , & ) to the expression. Were they necessary to locate the cells?

Comment: *"I was wondering why you added groups , & ) to the expression. Were they necessary to locate the cells?"*. Yes. Necessary to target single cells (instead of ranges) as well as to be able to add the $ to both columns and rows.